# delete dataframe by index from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe df1 and df2. I want to delete data from df2 based on the index from df1.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'index':[1,2,3,4],
                 'names':['andi','andrew','jhon','andreas']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'index':[1,2],
                 'names':['andi','andrew']})
```

expected output

```
index,names
3,jhon
4,andreas
```

Answer (score 4):

If need remove rows by index values use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df1.drop(df2.index)
print (df)
   index    names
2      3     jhon
3      4  andreas
```

If need remove values by columns called `index` use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and inverting mask by `~`:

```
df = df1[~df1['index'].isin(df2['index'])]
print (df)
   index    names
2      3     jhon
3      4  andreas
```

Or create index by both columns by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and use first solution:

```
df = df1.set_index('index').drop(df2.set_index('index').index)
print (df)
         names
index         
3         jhon
4      andreas
```

Comment: Thanks, sometime you search for easy question on google and didnt find any solution because bad keyword use. and ask a question in stackoverflow, and you the answer is actually one line. Thank you for your help